# Calculate amount of possible combinations of array with a length of 19 that can have 10 possible values

Tags: javascript

**Info**

I am trying to find the amount of possible combinations of an array with `7` or `19` values.

Starting point with `7` values `[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]`;

Starting point with `19` values `[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]`;

There are `10` possible values each position in the array can have: `0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5`

- Rule 1: The first value (index 0) can be a maximum of `3.5`
- Rule 2: The second value (index 1) can be a maximum of `4`
- Rule 3: Two neighbor values can not have a difference of more than `2.5`

Without the rules the answer would have just been 10<sup>7</sup> for 7 values and 10<sup>19</sup> for 19 values.

Rule 1 and 2 are also pretty easy to add to the calculation as we can just remove 2 possibilities for the first value and 1 for the second value.

7 values: 8 * 9 * 10<sup>5</sup> = 7200000

19 values: 8 * 9 * 10<sup>17</sup> = 7200000000000000000

**Problem**

The problem for me is how to calculate the amount of combinations possible with rule 3 considered.

I have tried a couple of iterative solutions and some recursive solutions that runs through each combination and add to a counter if it is valid according to the rules, but quickly figured out it would take way to long for it to finish as it would have to run 10<sup>19</sup> iterations for 19 values which would take years.

How can I calculate the amount of possible combinations with all 3 rules considered in a reasonable time.

**Code**

Here is the code I currently have which implements rule 1 and 2.

Note that I have used the `npm` module `bignumbers.js` to avoid rounding errors on big numbers.

```js
const BigNumber = require("bignumber.js");

const findCombinations = (n) => {
    let totalCombinations = BigNumber(1);

    for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if (i === n) {
            totalCombinations = totalCombinations.times(8);
        } else if (i === n - 1) {
            totalCombinations = totalCombinations.times(9);
        } else {
            totalCombinations = totalCombinations.times(10);
        }
    }

    return totalCombinations;
};

console.log(findCombinations(7).toFixed());
console.log(findCombinations(19).toFixed());
```

Comment: This looks like a math problem for [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/), not like a JavaScript question.

Comment: This is an interesting challenge - where is it from?

Comment: Having thought this through I'd agree that it can be a coding/logic problem, as this can be solved in code and does not have to be solved purely with math

Comment: Its a coding challenge from a Norwegian Christmas calendar hosted by a company called Knowit. I have simplified the description of the question though. Originally its about lock keys and the rules are for the cut of the notches in the keys and the possible values are the cut depths. So it is asking for how many possible combination of keys there are with 7 and 19 notches

Comment: I noticed you expanded the number of possible values from 9 to 10 - was this originally a mistake, or were you simplifying the question?

Comment: It was a mistake, i forgot to add the value 1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this separately calculating the number of combinations that end in a certain symbol as you go.

```
function amount(init, step, len) {
  if (len < 1) return 0;
  const countsByRoundAndLastSymbol = [Object.fromEntries(init.map(symbol => [symbol, 1n]))];
  for (let i=1; i<len; i++) {
    const prevCounts = countsByRoundAndLastSymbol[i-1]
    const counts = {};
    for (const [prevSymbol, prevCount] of Object.entries(prevCounts)) {
      for (const symbol of step(i, prevSymbol)) {
        counts[symbol] ??= 0n;
        counts[symbol] += prevCount;
      }
    }
    countsByRoundAndLastSymbol[i] = counts;
  }
  return Object.values(countsByRoundAndLastSymbol[len-1]).reduce((sum, count) => sum + count, 0n);
}
```

Now you can apply your rules:

```
const possibleValues = [0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5];
for (const len of [7, 19]) {
  console.log(`Possible combinations of length ${len}:`, amount(
    possibleValues.filter(x => x <= 3.5),
    (i, prevSymbol) => possibleValues.filter(x =>
      Math.abs(x - prevSymbol) <= 2.5 &&
      (i != 1 || x <= 4)
    ),
    len
  ));
}
```